# Linker Double Redirect (IAR EWARM)

Tags: linker, arm, stm32, iar

I have an IAR STM32 project where I am need to wrap a library function with some custom logic. I do not have the ability to recompile the library itself, so what I would like to do is create a function `libfunction_shim` that calls into the original `libfunction`. Using the `--redirect` linker option (`--redirect libfunction=libfunction_shim`), I can redirect calls to the original function to the shim, including calls inside the library itself. However, I need to call the original function from the shim.

If I add another redirect (`--redirect libfunction_original=libfunction`), it ends up redirecting `libfunction_original` to `libfunction_shim`, rather than the original `libfunction`. I've tried reordering the redirects, but it does the same thing regardless of order.

The linker log demonstrates this:

```
Symbol                     Redirected to          Reason        
-------------              ------                 ------
...
libfunction                libfunction_shim       command line  
libfunction_original       libfunction_shim       command line
```

What I would like this:

```
Symbol                     Redirected to          Reason        
-------------              ------                 ------
...
libfunction                libfunction_shim       command line  
libfunction_original       libfunction            command line
```

Is it possible to do this using the linker?

Comment: Why do you have to do this at linker level? In the other words, why not just call `libfunction_shim` at user code directly, or rename function using the preprocessor?

Comment: I need to redirect function calls internal to the library, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using linker redirects, you have to write your shim function in a specific way. A complete description is available in the manual (pg 225 in the 8.40.1 version) but to summarize: First you name the shim `$sub$$libfunction`, where `libfunction` is the name of the function to shadow. From inside the shim you can use `$super$$libfunction` to call the original version of `libfunction`. A minimal example is shown below.

```
extern void $Super$$foo(void);

void $Sub$$foo(void)
{
  $Super$$foo(); /* calls the original foo() function */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this trick ! Realy useful !